# Converting to int from string in public static

Tags: c#

```
private class global
{
    public static string str = label4.Text;
    int a = Convert.ToInt32(str);
}

private void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string myString = label4.Text;
    int Val = Int32.Parse(myString);
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(label2.Text, Val * global.a );
}
```

Hello guys I have some problem here, then I convert string to int in private void it works fine, but then I try to convert it on public global it shows errors, any ideas how to fix it?

> DB2.Form2.global.a' is inaccessible due to its protection level
>
> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'DB2.Form2.global.a
>
> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'DB2.Form2.label4

Comment: What dpo you want to achieve?

Comment: your int a = private. 
make it public.

Comment: You need to go back to the start and learn about classes and objects, access modifiers and what `static` means. None of the answers here are going to teach you this (whether they make your code compile or not).

Comment: You cannot access a private class private element from out side the class...it is private. The public static would only apply to the string not the int which would be at the class level private.

Comment: This code has a number of issues in it, and conversion is just one of them. why do you think you can assign `public static string str` from some arbitrary variable called `label`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a` is not visible outside the class `global`,  you should make it public:

```
public int a  = Convert.ToInt32(str);
```

Since the `global` class is not marked as `static` you either make it static or create an instance of `global`.

```
private static class global
{
    public static int a = ...
}
```

or when not making it static (but `a` must be public):

```
var myGlobal = new global();
int x = myGlobal.a;
```

Furthermore:

- classes should be capitalized

  ```
  public class Global { ... }
  ```
- Same goes for public properties/fields:

  ```
  public int A = 1;
  public string Str = "";
  ```

Answer (score 0):

`a` is not defined as a global static variable.

Redefine it as `public static int a;`

Comment: @SriramSakthivel good point. Removed that part.  Overall, the concept of OOP is getting missed here.

Comment: Even I miss concept of c#

Answer (score 0):

You can't access a field from a class without first instantiating an object unless that field is static and the field is accessible.

Comment: its a static class so he dont need to instantinate it.

Comment: it is not a static class and the variable `a` is certainly not static...

Comment: you are right. Its only one of the variables that is static. Both class an variable should be in my opinion.

Comment: yes, well, there are other issues with the class but thats a separate issue.

Answer (score 0):

your int is private int your global class.

Change it to public and static.

Answer (score 0):

a is not static and public. So either make it public static or instantiate the class and use the instance to access a.

private field can't be accessed outside of class.

Answer (score 0):

variable `a` is private and hence not accessible outside the class and moreover it's declared as instance member and not static member.

you need to declare it as `public static int a` based on your posted code usage

Your class definition should look like

```
private class global
{
    public static string str = label4.Text;
    public static int a;
    a = Convert.ToInt32(str);
}
```

First error `is inaccessible due to its protection level` cause because you declared `a` as private.

second error `An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property` caused because you were trying to access an instance member as static member.